# How do I change the security level to avoid "The security level is set to High" error when merging MS docs with Adobe Acrobat X Pro?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, adobe-acrobat, security-warning

I have MS Word 2010 and Adobe Acrobat x Pro (CS 5.5)

I get an error when I am trying to Combine two Word documents:

> The Security level is set to High. Please run the application which created this document, in the "Security Warning" dialog select the check box "Always trust macros from this source" and enable macros created by Adobe Systems Inc.

How can I resolve this error?